# How to list hidden file/process/regKeys by rootkit

Tags: c, windows, hide, rootkit

I wanted to know how can I list files or processes or registry keys that are hidden by a Rootkit?

For example, [gmer](http://www.gmer.net) does it, and I want to know how.

Thanks!

PS: My primary programming language is AutoIt, but any answer that is usable in standard C will be fine.

Comment: That's quite an in-depth project for a beginner. What have you tried?

Comment: You may begin with [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) [source code](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/)

Comment: You may want to check out these as well [oark](https://code.google.com/p/oark/), [arkitlib](https://code.google.com/p/arkitlib/). And, the book [Rootkits: Subverting the Windows Kernel](http://www.amazon.com/Rootkits-Subverting-Windows-Greg-Hoglund/dp/0321294319)

Comment: There is no answer to this question. For any technique you come up with, somebody can write a rootkit that specifically hides from it. it's like asking, "How can I prove that my entire reality is not a dream?"

Answer (score 0):

swatkat suggestions were very useful -- one of those linked to a Windows Internals course (which uses Win Int 5th Ed as a text): [CS490 Windows Internals](http://www.cs.sjtu.edu.cn/~kzhu/cs490/)